# Eclipse Luna Syntax Color Settings Disappear after Restart

Tags: java, css, eclipse, coldfusion, eclipse-luna

I recently updated to Eclipse Luna (4.4.1).  I use several plugins (eGit, CFBuilder, SOAPUI, etc).
I have customized my syntax color settings for HTML, CSS, Java, XML, and ColdFusion.  I have them exported to .col files so I can use the same colors on all my computers.

I can import and use my color settings fine.  However, when I close Eclipse, it seems to loose the settings.  Each time I restart Eclipse I have to go through and re-select each of the col files. This was not the case in older versions.

The files don't get moved.  In fact I keep them in a "customizations" folder inside my Eclipse install.

Is there some setting I need to choose to have it save the settings internally or the location of the import files???